# Taylor series for complex functions $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ and $f(z)=\log(g(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm looking for a good way of computing Taylor series for complex functions $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ and $f(z)=\log(g(z))$ ($f(z_0)$ is fixed for $z_0$ and there is a suitable plane cut). May be one can find them using Taylor series for real  $f(z)=\sqrt [n] {g(z)}$ and $f(z)=\log(g(z))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic branch of $\log(g(z))$ in a disk $B_r(z_0)$. By decreasing $r$ if necessary we can assume that
$$
 \left| \frac{g(z)}{g(z_0)} - 1\right| < 1
$$
for all $z \in B_r(z_0)$. Then
$$
 f(z) = f(z_0) + \operatorname{Log} \left(\frac{g(z)}{g(z_0)}\right)
$$
where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal branch of the logarithm (i.e. the one satisfying $\operatorname{Log}(1) = 0$). The Taylor series
$$
 \operatorname{Log}(1+w) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} w^n
$$
is valid for $|w| < 1$ so that substituting $w = \frac{g(z)}{g(z_0)} - 1$ allows to compute the Taylor series of $f$.

Similarly, if $f$ is a holomorphic branch of $(g(z))^{1/n}$ in a neighborhood of $z=z_0$ then
$$
 f(z) = f(z_0) \left(\frac{g(z)}{g(z_0)}\right)^{1/n}
$$
allows to compute the Taylor series of $g$ via the binomial series for $(1+w)^{1/n}$.